# Serverless Framework with Typescript and MySql simple Project to connect AWS API Gateway ,Lambda and Cognito

Tags: mysql, typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, knex.js

I'm new to TypeScript and want to write a very simple code with Serverless Framework, Typescript, AWS API Gateway, AWS Lambda, and AWS RDS (MySql), and Cognito. Also, I want to use Knex as well.
What I need is for this project to receive the JSON object as a request through API gateway (GET for return data and Post for inserting to MySql DB). that's it.

I've tried the typescript template at the serverless website and lots of other templates and sample projects on the internet but none of them support all these steps as simple (there are some but they have lots of other things which is too complicated for me to learn all of them at this stage)

So I was wondering if you know any simple project that can do this or if not I would be much grateful if you can let me know how I add Serverless config to a normal typescript project and make it automate for AWS.

I've already searched StackOverFlow for a similar question but couldn't find this if there is please let me know I'll delete this then.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same place as you.
Here I would like to leave you some repos links to see if they can help you achieve what you need.
As far as I know, the Cognito part is not too much complicated.
But for the RDS Mysql database, you need to play with VPC, subnets, and security groups. Wich I'm learning also.

https://github.com/tux86/nestjs-serverless-boilerplate

https://github.com/revstarconsulting/serverless-aws-nodejs-and-rds

https://github.com/xeusteerapat/ecommly-api

https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-typescript-starter

https://github.com/andrenbrandao/serverless-typescript-boilerplate

I hope some of this links, or maybe the fussion between them and their resources. Help you achive you goal :)
I'm playing with them, and so far it's been an amazing learning journey, besides I couldn't found yet, a proper AWS RDS Mysql configuration....

Edit for one post I liked and I took as an example also:

https://montecha.com/blog/creating-an-rds-proxy-using-serverless-framework/